# How to enforce Delphi Coding Standards

Tags: delphi, coding-style

I want to **enforce coding standards** for our **Delphi codebase**.

A few colleagues have suggested Code Healer and Pascal Analyzer. I've had a look at these tools and they aren't suitable.

I was hoping to be able to do the same thing that CheckStyle for Java or StyleCop for C# can do

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? If I'm not mistaken, Delphi 2010 at least has tools to aid you in this.

Comment: We're using the Professional version, so I don't think a lot of those tools will be available. I will check it out anyway. Thanks.

Comment: How about "code review" that includes all kinds of "lint" checks including certain coding standards?  There are conventions like T prefix on regular class names, and E prefix on exception class names, and F prefix on private data fields in classes, that should be flagged and fixed wherever they are violated. However coding standards like indentation are better to fix by "fixing" them by running them through a formatter, than by "checking" if they need fixing.

Comment: This kind of question would probably get instantly closed in 2018-2020 era due to it being basically a tool recommendation question.  It's sad really that someone decided that because questions like this are certainly useful.

Answer (score 4):

The best one is [Pascal Analyzer](https://www.peganza.com/products_pal.html) (PAL) by Peganza, which you said you tried and found unsuitable, but did not say why. I will say a bit in its favor: It's Commercial, inexpensive, and so worth it.  They recently released version 5, and if version 5 doesn't do what you want, you should tell them what you want, because they have always answered my requests whenever I have mentioned a feature I wish the product would add.

We use it instead of the high-end SKUs of Delphi's metrics because it costs less and does more than the built-in $3000 stuff. I think it costs about $160 us.

I am a *happy customer*. Here is a sample of some of the metric areas that I like:
convention compliance - class names that don't start with T, exception types don't start with E, class fields not in private, identifiers with goofy names, class visibility confusion or bad order, local identifier/unit outer scope identifier clashes.  Inconsistent case, Many many many more!

[image]

The weakness is that the output is plain text in a "TMemo" control.  Of course, I have found a lot of ways to take that output and write my own small sort/filter utilities to mine even more useful stuff from the reports.  A powerful tool that you won't be able to live without once you try it.

I realize you said in your answer that you tried that already, but if it's not what you want, it's already the best LINT like tool for Pascal that currently exists.

Comment: Thanks Warren. Pascal Analyzer certainly is a very good piece of software. We currently use PAL for the metrics it produces. However, we found that the "convention compliance" checks were very basic and no where near as comprehensive as CheckStyle is for Java. Also, PAL doesn't allow you to write your own checks (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: The ability to use PAL's parser plus your own strings (regex + some boolean logic conditions) would be a fabulous idea to suggest to the PAL guys. If you don't, I will.

Comment: I also bought PAL about a month ago. This is an excellent tool! Now you can set Limits. Assume you have 50 warnings of type REDU24. Just add REDU24=50 in a file Limits.txt. And refer that from PALCmd.exe. If warnings of type REDU24 is 50 or less the errorlevel is 0 else 99. This way you can slowly decrease warnings as time goes.

Comment: It remains in 2020 a great tool.

Answer (score 3):

It seems those 2 are the most used. You can also try:

http://jedicodeformat.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Radu, but I'm more interested in a tool that produces a report, rather than a tool that actually goes ahead and reformats the code.

Answer (score 3):

Some newer editions of Delphi offer [Audits and Metrics](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39931) in the Model view, which can also be configured to set allowed limits. They do not run from command line for build integration afaik so I found them not very helpful.

I know the highly customizable Java (and .Net tools) like PMD, FindBugs and CheckStyle which generate XML or HTML statistic reports, and also integrate very well with build tools (Ant, Maven, Hudosn) - but for Delphi nothing comparable has crossed my road so far.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Unfortunately, it does appear that Delphi does lag behind quite a bit in this area.

Comment: "Audits and Metrics" is not available in the Professional version. You need "Enterprise" or higher.

Comment: 10+ introductory level code metrics and 10 introductory level code audits are included in Delphi 2010 Professional (see my link), I guess that they are in XE too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into writing your own style checking, you can write a .exe in Delphi to look for bad things being committed.  Call that in a pre-commit hook into your repository.
You can examine the differences of a checkin by using SVNLOOK.
ex:

excerpt from pre-commit.bat

```
SVNLOOK diff -t "%2" "%1" | MyCustomFilter.exe
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO EOJ
EXIT 1
:EOJ
EXIT 0
```